# Randomize struct members order on compile

Tags: c++

This question is actually more out of curiosity as I do not want to personally achieve this. I'm reversing and translating back to source code a game that was written mostly in C++.

This game has quite a few structs used to represent entities, such as units, levels and what not. Now, some of these structs, with every new patch they have released, got their members completely re-arranged, in a what seems to be random order.

For example, a given struct on version 1.10 would look like this:

```
struct DrlgLevel
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int e;
};
```

And then on version 1.11, the same struct would look like this:

```
struct DrlgLevel
{
    int c;
    int a;
    int b;
    int e;
    int d;
};
```

The functionalities using these structs usually haven't changed between versions, I'm pretty sure the sole purpose of this randomization is to make it harder to reverse, some obfuscation against reverse engineering.

So now, my actual question is, is there a way to tell the compiler to do this, or perhaps on a pre-processor level, or is it something they'd be doing manually on every new patch? Sounds like it could be done easily for the compiler but I've searched and tried to look through various compile options and couldn't find anything.

Thanks.

Comment: Things like that are easily done by a custom source code pre-processor. It wouldn't make much sense to implement such functionality in compilers.

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't optimally formulated but I meant to ask, is it possible to do without hard-retyping the struct definition. Be it via pre-processing, compile-time randomizing, etc.

Comment: The compiler isn't allowed to do this. It is required to assign offsets to these elements in increasing order as they appear in the definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really a useful feature in terms of the *compiler* but it can be done with some quite easy pre-processing.

First, separate it into *two* files, a non-randomised-order input file and your original file which includes a randomised-order equivalent):

```
randomOrder.h.in:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int e;
<your actual file containing the structure>:
    struct DrlgLevel {
        #include "randomOrder.h"
    };
```

Then, before the actual compilation step (i.e., before you compile *any* code that uses that header file), run a script which will create it from `randomOrder.h.in`:

```
shuf randomOrder.h.in >randomOrder.h
```

If you're on a platform without `shuf`, you can still *do* it, you just have to find the equivalent tool that can do the job, such as PowerShell in Windows ( or `sort -R` or `awk` if your *nix distro is missing `shuf` for some bizarre reason). Or you could try to *locate* a `shuf` executable for your platform and use it.

But the tool you *use* is not really important, it's the fact that you can reliably and repeated construct a randomly-ordered field list before compiling the code.

Comment: There is a `shuf` command which shuffles the input, no need for extra tools.

Comment: Good show, @Ivan, I have to admit I didn't know about that one - I've added it to the answer.

Comment: You're welcome! By the way, if one doesn't have `shuf`, there may exist `sort -R` which does exactly the same thing.

Comment: I was looking for an answer within the compiler or the C++ language itself (pre-processor directives for example), some "built-in" feature, but from all the answers and comments this doesn't seem to exist. Accepted answer and +1 because your answer is the most plausible way to achieve this, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

its a horrible idea. IF you did this, how would the object files link, unless you compiled everything from a single source file?

IF you really really wanted this, you would have to change the headder file that contained the struct definition prior to each compile, this could be scripted if one really wanted